# Chrome getting black screen while capture image/Video

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I am trying to capture image and video of chrome screen getting the black screen. and when I minimise chrome it's working properly... I tried 2-3 screen capture tools but same black screen any idea ? I just google and find out some related to admin setting... but I didn't get anything more and so is there any chrome admin setting that disable screen capture ?